# @rally.user.subscription.workspaces is returning undefined method 'workspaces' for nil:NilClass

Tags: rally

I know my userid have workspace set on rally login when accessed via browser, but when accessed via rest api it's not returning any subscription for that login user.

Does it goes back to Rally configuration or need to with API itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your base url when you setup RallyRestAPI.new?  sometimes if there is something wrong there, it will do this.
Make sure it is something like:  https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm

Hope that helps.

Comment: No. We have moved to SSO integration and hence that url is not being used right now.

Comment: The rally_rest_api unfortunately isn't setup to support SSO sign-in. You'll need to ask one of your Rally administrators to add your login credentials to the SSO white-list (Setup->Subscription, as a Sub Admin) so that you can go back to using Rally-only credentials for ruby scripting.

Comment: Even after that, it's erroring out when it is getting error in following line -> workspaces = @rally.user.subscription.workspaces...So following error is being returned "@rally.user.subscription.workspaces is returning undefined method 'workspaces' for nil:NilClass"......Is it rally error that my subscription is not being returned?

Comment: Did you check your base URL per Dave's suggestion? Can you post your code or an excerpt thereof? It is difficult to assist without it.

Comment: Well here is the output of ruby config_test.rb ->ruby config_test.rb
1.Log file write Passed.
2.Server appears to be outside of Rally. Do you have an on-premise installation?
3.Successfully connected to Rally
4.Rally Workspace Error - ''undefined method `workspaces' for nil:NilClass
5.Email Validation Passed

Comment: log file shows INFO -- : Rally Connector triggered...
DEBUG -- : Entering read_xml_config_file
DEBUG -- : RallyUsername: abcd@xyz.org
DEBUG -- : RallyBaseUrl: https://rally1.rallydev.com
DEBUG -- : RallyWorkspaceName: Workspace
DEBUG -- : RallySCMRepositoryName: Repository1
DEBUG -- : UserDomain: xyz.org
DEBUG -- : Rally User field for SCM User: 
DEBUG -- : SourceControlUrl: http://localhost:9890
DEBUG -- : Entering get_states
INFO -- : Artifact States not stored in config file
DEBUG -- : Leaving read_xml_config

Comment: Was able to make it working once i reverted back the rb script changes.